# Send two EventArgs to the same event handler?

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling

I want to send `FileSystemEventArgs` *and* `RenamedEventArgs` to the same event handler. Is this possible?

Something like...

```
watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnChanged);

private void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e, RenamedEventArgs r)
{
}
```

I am sending multiple events to the same handler and only one of them sends `RenamedEventArgs`, but I still need `FileSystemEventArgs` for the others.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Are you (i.e. code you are in charge of) responsible for firing that `Renamed` event?

Comment: @HansPassant But using just `RenamedEventArgs` does not work for event types other than `Renamed`.

Comment: you should just pull out the code in the onchanged into a method that can be called for both onchanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) and onchanged(object sender, RenamedEventArgs r)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.You can't change the signature of your method, it has to match with your `EventHandler` delegate.

If you were using a custom event, you could declare your own `EventHandler` delegate.but it seems this is the [`FileSystemWatcher.Renamed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.renamed.aspx) event so there is no way to change a definition of built-in event.

Comment: So can I make the delegate match such a method?